# Geometric Progression - Finding the element

Tags: sequences-and-series

> In the geometric sequence whose first element is $0.0003$ and whose common ratio is $10$, which element is $3000000$?

I think I've figured out how to solve this, but I'm stuck at a particular step. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be heplful if you include the particular step where you are stuck.

Comment: for the future, include your answer and add the tag [solution-verification] or [proof-verification]

Comment: Alright, thank you! I am a beginner in this website :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. A geometric sequence with initial element $a$ and common ratio $r$ is given by
$$a,ar,ar^2,ar^3,ar^4,\dots, \underbrace{ar^{n-1}}_{\text{$n$th element}},\dots$$
So the question is if $a=0.0003$ and $r=10$ then for which integer $n$ we have that
$$ar^{n-1}=3\cdot 10^{-4}\cdot 10^{n-1}=3\cdot 10^{n-5}\stackrel{?}{=}3\cdot 10^6=3000000.$$

Can you take it from here? Recall that $10^a=10^b$ iff $a=b$.

Comment: This is the method that I applied :) However I am stuck at this step: 1x10^10 = 10^(n-1) I don't know how to get isolate n,unfortunately

Comment: Note that $10^a=10^b$ iff $a=b$.

Comment: Thank you!!! I finally got the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Note first element, $a = 0.0003 = 3 × 10^{-4} $ and common ratio, $r = 10$. Thus, the formula of the nth term is: $$ar^{n-1} = T_n $$ since $T_1 = a, T_2 = ar$ and so on....

Substitute for $T_n $ and you will get the answer.

Comment: This is the method that I applied :) However I am stuck at this step:
1x10^10 = 10^(n-1) I don't know how to get isolate n,unfortunately

Comment: @m18 See, $T_n = 3000000 = 3×10^{6}$. You will get $n-1$ on substitution in the formula. Then get $n $.

Comment: @m18 $10^{10} = 10^{n-1} $ implies $10 = n - 1$ as the base is equal.

Comment: @m18 You have $10^{10} = 10^{n-1}$, you say? What could the exponent on the right-hand side, $n-1$, possibly be? Also note that this is _exactly_ the kind of information you should have included in the question to begin with. Instead, you now have two answers telling you what you have already done.